# Issue with loading localhost site in IFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have a MVC site that I want to load into Iframe. I have added the X-Frame-Options to AllowAll. When I try to load the site, I can see the html document in developer tools but the IFrame in the Page is blank.

I tried to create a web application on localohost with different port number and where I tried to load the MVC site in Iframe, it didnt work.
I tried to add a html in the same MVC site and loading itself in the html's Iframe (assuming port issue but still it will not load).

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue. The `X-Frame-Options` header did not work for me. I had to use the `Content-Security-Policy` header. In the `web.config` file, I set it to `frame-src https://my-domain.com` like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-src {your domain here}" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I did this but still no luck:    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear/>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-src http://localhost:50569" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: I have never tried localhost, but it might work if you set `Content-Security-Policy` to `value="frame-src 'self'"` or try without the port number: `value="frame-src localhost"`